# What is the prefered way of writing methods in Laravel?

Tags: php, methods, laravel, convention

Which one of these styles are prefered when retrieving data to display in a view?

Straight forward laravel with no custom methods in the model:

```
$guest->bookings->first()->id;
$guest->bookings->first()->bed;
$guest->bookings->first()->date;
```

or a method to get the latest booking model:

```
$guest->getLatestBooking()->id;
$guest->getLatestBooking()->bed;
$guest->getLatestBooking()->date;
```

or seperate methods for each value like this:

```
$guest->getLatestBookingId();
$guest->getLatestBookingBed();
$guest->getLatestBookingDate();
```

Comment: I'd say the second one, but it's a matter of preference and you won't be able to get one single correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you need to attach other queries (like 'where', or 'select'). This doesn't mean that you always have to use the second option, third is excellent too. For the first one, try to avoid it.